# FFmpeg: For NVENC, what is a concurrent surface?

Tags: ffmpeg

When I type in this command to see all encoding options: `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc`, it says this:

```
-surfaces          <int>        E..V...... Number of concurrent surfaces (from 0 to 64) (default 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What is a concurrent surface?

Memory on a Graphics card:

> A common feature of many hardware decoders to be able to generate output in hardware surfaces suitable for use by other components (with discrete graphics cards, this means surfaces in the memory on the card rather than in system memory) – this is often useful for playback, as no further copying is required before rendering the output, and in some cases it can also be used with encoders supporting hardware surface input to avoid any copying at all in transcode cases.

Source: [HWAccelIntro – FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro)

Further Reading: [NVIDIA FFmpeg Transcoding Guide | NVIDIA Technical Blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/)